# docker login into nexus connection refused

Tags: docker, centos, docker-compose, nexus3

I have set up my docker repo, below is the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '2'

networks:
  prodnetwork:
    driver: bridge

services:
 nexus:
  image: sonatype/nexus3
  volumes:
   - "nexus-data:/nexus-data"
  ports:
   - "8081:8081"
   - "8082:8082"
   - "8083:8083"
   - "8084:8084"
   - "8085:8085"
   - "8086:8086"
   - "8087:8087"
   - "8088:8088"
  networks:
   - prodnetwork

 jenkins:
  image: library/jenkins
  ports:
    - "8080:8080"
  networks:
    - prodnetwork
  volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    - /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker
    - /opt/jenkins/:/var/lib/jenkins/
  depends_on:
    - nexus
    - sonar
  environment:
    - NEXUS_PORT=8081
    - SONAR_PORT=9000
    - SONAR_DB_PORT=5432

 sonar:
  build: ./sonar
  ports:
   - "9000:9000"
   - "5432:5432"
  networks:
    - prodnetwork
  depends_on:
    - sonardb
  environment:
   - SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL=jdbc:postgresql://sonardb:5432/sonar
   - SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME=sonar
   - SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD=sonar
 sonardb:
  networks:
    - prodnetwork
  image: postgres
  environment:
   - POSTGRES_USER=sonar
   - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=sonar
  volumes:
    - /opt/postgres/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  nexus-data: {}
```

In the file `docker.service` I have added:

```
DOCKER_OPTS=”$DOCKER_OPTS –insecure-registry=192.168.200.150:8083″
```

In the nexus 3 I have created repo with http port: `8083` and https: `8123`.

when I am trying to login by command

```
docker login -u admin 192.168.200.150:8083
```

or `8123` and type in correct password for nexus admin it is written:

```
Error response from daemon: Get https://192.168.200.150:8083/v2/: dial tcp 192.168.200.150:8083: getskopt: connection refused.
```

or

```
Error response from daemon: Get https://192.168.200.150:8083/v2/: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client
```

Do you have an idea how can I do that? I am stuck with it :/
I am using **CentOs** linux

Comment: is the url https://192.168.200.150:8083/v2/_catalog returning result. If not the registry is not working.

Comment: I have respond like this:
{"repositories":[]}

Comment: can u try with port 8081 to connect?

Comment: not really. I have used jenkins 8080, nexus 8081 (I mean I am connecting to GUI by this one)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for http, edit the docker registry, mark the "Create an HTTP connector at specified port. Normally used if the server is behind a secure proxy." 
set the port to 8083 and it's[image] done.

Answer (score 4):

You just need to expose your selected port before run your container with this command:

```sh
docker run -d -p 8081:8081 -p 8082:8082 --name nexus sonatype/nexus3
```

first port(`8081`) use to nexus itself and second port (`8082`) use to http connector in configuration.

that's it!

Answer (score 1):

Few days ago I came across this issue myself. If you have a look at the Docker Nexus 3 logs you should see that it cannot allocate the given ports for some reasons (or at least in my case). The way I have fixed this was to have a look at the Nexus documentation and edit jetty-https.xml, nexus.properties and org.sonatype.nexus.cfg as https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/217542177 and https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/231723267-How-to-Upgrade-Nexus-Repository-Manager-3-0-2-to-3-1-0-or-Later

Comment: But is it possible to do those steps if my nexus is in docker image?

Comment: Well looking at your docker-compose file, you have mounted 'nexus-data' as a volume which is great, in case of failure you will have the data there, however, if the container does fail all your customer configuration might be lost. So the way I have approached this was building another image based on the Nexus 'official' image with the config I need it.

Comment: being honest. I thought that this is official one. Maybe I was wrong. I am not scared of losing data, cause I didnt have enough time to add any ;). You mean that you have downloaded nexus files and add into docker-compose.file addnotation: 
buiil: path_to_nexus_files ??

Comment: The image you are using is the official one as I do too, however, like I have said, but take for example you might want to use SSL certificates, therefore, you will have to add it to your container, so if the container goes bust, when you will re-start it you will have to do so manually. If that's ok with you, then is ok :) So yes I have downloaded the need it files and edited them accordingly, then I have build an image from sonatype/nexus3

Comment: Ok, I will try that way. Hope it works ;). Thank you

Comment: If I may ask. How did you checked NEXUS DOMAIN of your nexus host?

Comment: I don't quiet get your question :(

Comment: Hmm, in fact that was a stupid question of me. Sorry to bother ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Install nexus as a container**

1. docker run -u root -d -p 8081:8081 -p 8083:8083 --name nexus -v $(pwd)/nexus-data:/nexus-data sonatype/nexus3
2. open the port in security groups 8081 and 8083
3. add the insecure repository on docker host machine
4. $ sudo vi /etc/docker/daemon.json

   {
   "insecure-registries" : ["*`host`*:8083"]
   }
5. restart the docker deamon.
   $ sudo service docker restart
6. docker login -u admin -p ****** *`host`*:8083
7. docker tag hat-app:v2 *`host`*:8083/chat-app:v2
8. docker push *`host`*:8083/chat-app:v2